# Python How to add a value to a dictionary value

Tags: python

So I have this code (python):

```
 dictionary = {
    gold:10   
}
```

How can I add 50 to the value to the dictionary.gold

Comment: Too silly question.

Comment: I think I should apologize for my comment as you are only 7 years old. But it 's still not a suitable question for this website. You should read at least one book about python to learn basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary['gold'] += 50
```

You can use in-place addition.

Comment: Thanks Im asking this question because im only 7 yrs old